# How to order a child of has_one relationship by attributes inside a controller using Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models as a child from has_one relationship like this:

```
class HotelThai < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :hotel

  #validates :hotel_id, presence: true
  validates :hotel_name, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true

end

class HotelEng < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :hotel

  validates :hotel_name, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true

end
```

And this is my Parent Model:

```
class Hotel < ApplicationRecord

  mount_uploader :logo, PromotionImageUploader
  mount_uploader :image_url, PromotionImageUploader
  mount_uploader :banner, PromotionImageUploader

  validates :logo, presence: true
  validates :image_url, presence: true
  validates :banner, presence: true

  validates :hotel_link, presence: true

  has_one :hotel_thai ,dependent: :destroy
  has_one :hotel_eng ,dependent: :destroy

  validates_associated :hotel_thai
  validates_associated :hotel_eng

end
```

Then on the controller i need to get a hotel data order by child `hotel_thai` or `hotel_eng` (depending on current language) with `hotel_name` attribute.

I tried it with this:

```
def index
    @normal_hotel = nil
    if I18n.locale == :en
      @normal_hotel = Hotel.where(is_highlight: false).order('hotel_eng.hotel_name ASC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    elsif I18n.locale == :th
      @normal_hotel = Hotel.where(is_highlight: false).order('hotel_thai.hotel_name ASC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    else
      @normal_hotel = Hotel.where(is_highlight: false).order('hotel_eng.hotel_name ASC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    end

    normal_hotel_group = @normal_hotel.in_groups(2)
    @left_normal_hotel = normal_hotel_group[0]
    @right_normal_hotel = normal_hotel_group[1]

    @highlight_hotel = Hotel.where(is_highlight: true)
    highlight_hotel_group = @highlight_hotel.in_groups(2)
    @left_highlight_hotel = highlight_hotel_group[0]
    @right_highlight_hotel = highlight_hotel_group[1]
  end
```

But this is what I got:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "hotel_eng" LINE 1: ...tels" WHERE "hotels"."is_highlight" = $1 ORDER BY hotel_eng.... ^ : SELECT "hotels".* FROM "hotels" WHERE "hotels"."is_highlight" = $1 ORDER BY hotel_eng.hotel_name ASC LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3
```

So does anyone know how to fix this, or another way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join related tables if you want to use order by theirs columns. Use `joins` or `includes` methods for this

```
def index
  hotel = I18n.locale == :th ? :hotel_thai : :hotel_eng
  @normal_hotel = Hotel.where(is_highlight: false).
    joins(hotel).order("#{hotel.to_s.pluralize}.hotel_name ASC").
    paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  normal_hotel_group = @normal_hotel.in_groups(2)
  ...
end
```

Comment: use `pluralize` method in order state